# how to select product according to the category

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code in categories

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY cat_id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
    ?>
        <li><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row["cat_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["categoriesname"]; ?></a><li>
```

and This is my code in product.php

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
    ?>

  <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <form method="post" action="orders.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
      <br>
      <div style="border:5px solid #5cb85c; background-color:whitesmoke; border-radius:10px; padding:20px; height:420px" align="center">
        <h4 class="text-success"><?php echo $row["product_category"]; ?></h4>

        <img src="admin/public/img/<?php echo $row["images"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" width="200" height="300"/>

        <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["product_name"]; ?></h4>

        <h4 class="text-danger">₱ <?php echo $row["product_price"]; ?></h4>

        <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />

        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["product_name"]; ?>" />

        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_image" value="<?php echo $row["images"]; ?>" />

        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["product_price"]; ?>" />
        <br>

        <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

how to do that? how to select according to the category? this is shopping cart...I want to show all of the product by selecting the category..

Answer (score 0):

You need a relationship between these 2 tables(product and categories) to do that.

add cat_id in product table as a foreign key(primary key located in another table).
then use the following MySQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` 
        INNER JOIN 
              `categories` 
        ON product.cat_id = categories.cat_id 
        WHERE categoriesname = <CategoryName>;
```

#### Update

your problem seems concerned with the syntax try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_id = '" . $_GET['cat_id'] ."' ORDER BY id";
```

#### Update 2

Your problem is you trying to access cat_id column that doesn't exist in your product table.

please use the following MySQL code for adding cat_id column inside product table as foreign key(make sure cat_id is primary key in categories table)
`` ALTER TABLE `product` ADD FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES categories(cat_id); ``

Comment: But if i don't have cat_id table in product what mysql code i use?

Comment: I made an update in my answer, check it

Comment: i use this $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_id = '" . $_GET['cat_id'] ."' ORDER BY id";  but undefined index: cat_id

Comment: do you have cat_id  column in the Product table?

Comment: no i don't have

Comment: then you have to create that, it is impossible  to do that without having cat_id

Comment: I have made another update, check it

Comment: ALTER TABLE `product` ADD FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES categories(cat_id); where i should put this?

Comment: if you are using phpMyAdmin you can navigate to SQL and execute the command or if you are using MySQL in the command line you just need to execute it directly.                           Which database client you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the table for info?

Im just gessing, but if you have the cat_id as secondary_key in the product table, you should be able to filter your query with your given $_GET['id'] - not sure if you have done like this, but your query for the product list should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE `cat_id` = '$cat_id' ORDER BY id
```

Be careful when working with variables that can be set by a user, they can be modified - so always (+ other security checks) use something like mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) to prevent SQL Injection.

If you need more info, you can post your table infos as well!

Comment: I don't have cat_id table in the product..What should i do?

Comment: This is my code in the admin when I addproduct and then
        <select class="form-control" name="product_category">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY cat_id";
        $result = mysqli_query( $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row["categoriesname"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["categoriesname"]; ?></option>

Comment: I use this code $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_id =  '$_GET['cat_id']' ORDER BY id"; but error syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

Check your column name : cat_id (It is category id belong to category.)

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
   $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_id = '" . $_GET['id'] ."' ORDER BY id";
} else{
   echo 'Please select category';
}
```